# Xcode - Trying to run on IPhone - Signing wont work

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, code-signing

I'm trying to get my react native app to run on an iPhone plugged in via USB.

I have added my apple Id and it is listed in the "Preferences>Accounts" section. It is not a "developer program" id, yet. but I'm told that shouldn't matter.

If I go into "Manage Certificates" I see:
"Signing certificates for "Me"
all of the certificates have status "Missing Private Key". There is one titled "me's MacBook Air" and about another 15 "Untitled".

I have selected my phone via "Product > Destination".

When I go into "MyProj > General > Signing" I have set "Team" to be "Me (Personal Team)"

"Signing > Status" shows two errors:
"The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct"
"No profile for 'org.blah.MyProj' were found"

I cannot resolve these issues, and pressing the Play button shows "Build failed". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://%20https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/3263):

"joshaber commented on Nov 16, 2017 •

It sure looks like something's screwy with Keychain.

Try opening Keychain Access.app. Right-click on the login keychain and try locking it and then unlocking it again."

Turns out something in Keychain gets corrupted by a MacOS update - this is not too uncommon apparently.